# different templates - how to connect via landing page to next layout

Tags: templates, joomla

I am developing a site for a friend of mine. The startpage should only contain her name, a slogan and a link (something like Enter Site) to the next template. I can't figure out on how this can be accomplished.
So, briefly, the startpage should NOT contain menu items, the next template which would be called from the link "enter site" would contain ALL the menu items and the relevant information..

I have searched thru various discussion groups, but can't find an answer. Site is being build around Joomla CMS 3.2.3
URL is (for development purposes) www.webmatix.be/nikie

Can someone throw in a helping hand?

Tnx + b rgds

Gino

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Joomla and should be migrated to the [Joomla StackExchange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

there are various ways to achieve this. I guess that Joomla wants you to assign a different template to the home menu item. You can do this in extensions - templates. If you click on the template there is an option somewhere to add it to menu pages. So in fact you have to make 2 templates then. This is not what I prefer.

I always do it using PHP in my template's index.php. I ask for the menu's alias and then fix the template accordingly:

```
<?php 
    $currentMenuItem = JSite::getMenu()->getActive();
    $alias = $currentMenuItem->alias; 
?>
<?php if($alias == "home"): ?>
    <div>homepagestuffs</div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div>normal template with all kinds of modules and components bla</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This gives me the flexibility I want without having a second template to worry about.

Comment: For Joomla 3.x, you should be using the `JFactory::getApplication()` method to get the active menu item properties, not `JSite`

Comment: It's still not deprecated.. So the code above works just fine.

Comment: Fair, but it's the method used for 1.5. It's recommended what I've written above as proven here: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring for a moment the negative effect on user experience, why not just create an `index.html` in the root directory of the website and ***only if necessary*** adjust the `.htaccess` to promote it before `index.php` for just that directory.

e.g.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a HTML file like index.html and do what ever you want in that.
Place index.html in the root folder of your host.
Then make a folder and give it name like "dynamic" or whatever you want.
Copy the whole Joomla Website files in that folder.
The URLs would be like:

http://www.example.com/index.html
http://www.example.com/dynamic/index.php

I've one use this solution in [rasoularam.com](http://rasoularam.com)
The first page (landing page):[rasoularam.com](http://rasoularam.com), pure HTML, Javascript, CSS
The other pages: http://rasoularam.com/dynamic/index.php/%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%88%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%81%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%84-%D8%A2%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85.html

Do't worry about unfamiliar characters in the url, they are uni-code urls, written in persian.

The benefit of this solution is that, because of using pure html page as landing page, the first page will load fast, even the host does not have good hardware configuration.

The only problem is the administrator section's url would be [rasoularam.com/dynamic/administrator](http://rasoularam.com/dynamic/administrator)